# Gilbreath's Conjecture

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

Suppose we start with the infinite list of prime numbers:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, ...
```

Then, we take the absolute differences between each pair of numbers, repeatedly:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 6, 2, 6, 4, ...
[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 4, 2, ...
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, ...
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, ...
```

Notice that the leading number is 1 every time. [Gilbreath's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture) is the prediction that this continues to be the case forever.

The only way the leading number would stop being a 1 is if the next number after it was neither a 0 nor a 2. The only way the second number wouldn't be a 0 or a 2 is if the number after that was neither a 0 nor a 2. And so on.

The index of the earliest number, other than the leading 1, which is neither a 0 nor a 2, can never go down by more than 1 between a consecutive pair of sequences. This fact has been used to put a very strong lower bound on when, if ever, a sequence might not have a 1 as the first element.

In this challenge, you will be given the index of a sequence, and you must output the index of the first number in that sequence which is not the leading 1, and is not a 0 or a 2.

For instance, in the 4th absolute difference sequence above:

```
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, ...
```

The first entry that's neither a zero or a two, other than the first entry, is the 15th position, 14 zero indexed. So if the input was 4, you would output 14.

For inputs from 1 to 30, the outputs should be:

`[3, 8, 14, 14, 25, 24, 23, 22, 25, 59, 98, 97, 98, 97, 174, 176, 176, 176, 176, 291, 290, 289, 740, 874, 873, 872, 873, 872, 871, 870]`

This is [OEIS A000232](https://oeis.org/A000232).

This is assuming you have 1 indexed inputs and 0 indexed outputs. You may index your inputs and outputs starting at any constant integers, as long as you can accept the range of inputs corresponding to all sequences.

Requirements: Your solution must run in at most 1 minute on a input of up to 30. If it's close enough that it depends on the computer specs, it's allowed.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Can I 2-index my input?

Comment: @LeakyNun Sure.

Comment: Can output use _input_-based indexing?

Comment: @LuisMendo Correct, fixed. No, the indexing must be a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ÆNạ2\Ḋ¿Ḣ’Ị
R‘ÇÐ¿L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AS4A0f//w4ZO4bqhMlzhuIrCv@G4ouKAmeG7igpS4oCYw4fDkMK/TP8ycjMxw4figqz/)

Input is 2-indexing. Output is 1-indexing.

On TIO all testcases in total take 22.309 s.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 66 bytes

```
(For[z=1,Last@Nest[Abs@*Differences,Array[Prime,z+#],#]<3,z++];z)&
```

Pure function taking a positive integer as argument and returning a 1-indexed integer. `Nest[Abs@*Differences,Array[Prime,z+#],#]` computes the `#`th iterated absolute difference list of the list of the first `z+#` primes. `For[z=1,Last@...<3,z++]` loops this computation until the last element of the resulting list is at least `3`, and then `z` is output. (Note that the correctness of the algorithm assumes Gilbreath's conjecture!)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 32 bytes

```
-l.W>3h.WtHaVZtZ>QH+ZfP_TheZ.fP_
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-l.W%3E3h.WtHaVZtZ%3EQH%2BZfP_TheZ.fP_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A31&debug=0)

Uses 2-indexing.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 18 bytes

```
`@:YqG:"d|]3<A}@G-
```

Input and output are 1-based. It takes less than 40 seconds in TIO for each of the test cases.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5/gYBVZ6G6llFITa2zjWOvgrvv/v7EBAA)

#### Explanation

This keeps trying longer initial sequences of primes until the iterated absolute consecutive differences give at least one value exceeding `2`.

```
`        % Do... while loop
  @:Yq   %   Array of first k primes, where k is iteration index
  G:"    %   Do this as many times as the input
    d|   %     Absolute value of consecutive differences
  ]      %   End
  3<A    %   Are they all less than 3? This is the loop condition
}        % Finally (execute before exiting loop)
  @G-    %   Push last iteration index minus input. This is the output
         % End (implicit). Continue with next iteration if top of stack is true
         % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>136</s> 120 bytes

```
{->\i,\n{i??&?BLOCK(i-1,lazy
n.rotor(2=>-1).map: {abs .[1]-.[0]})!!1+n.skip.first:
:k,none 0,2}($_,grep &is-prime,2..*)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
{   # Anonymous function with argument in $_
    sub f(\i, \n) {  # Recursive helper function
        if i != 0 {  # If we're not done,
            # Recurse on the absolute differences between adjacent entries:
            f(i - 1, lazy n.rotor(2 => -1).map: { abs .[1] - .[0] });
        } else {
            # Otherwise, return the first index after 0
            # where the value is neither 0 nor 2.
            1 + n.skip.first: :k, none 0, 2;
        }
    }
    # Call the helper function with the argument passed to the top-level
    # anonymous function (the recursion depth), and with the prime numbers
    # as the initial (infinite, lazy) list:
    f($_, grep &is-prime, 2 .. *);
}
```

With an input of 30, the function runs in about four seconds on my modest laptop.

...which becomes 1.4 seconds after upgrading my seven-month-old Perl 6 installation (which also gives me the `skip` method that lets me shave off several bytes from my first solution).  All test cases from 1 to 30 take about ten seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 94 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:r)=abs(a-b):f(b:r)
length.fst.span(<3).(iterate f[n|n<-[2..],all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcjBCsMgDADQ@74ihR0SWEO73krdjxQPkakraCbW4/7d0eN7PaCsbq1kxJ0oo6M14OVbNMlrbB8OZ@OziOK2EOPRfJXmIez6023cn8z2ISkhvibi/H2D0pU6ztYOA/Ush4KBUg9tcIcsBSLsM/My2f4H) The last line is an anonymous function. Bind to e.g. `g` and call like `g 4`. All test cases combined take less than 2 seconds on TIO.

#### How it works

`[n|n<-[2..],all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]]` generates an infinite list of primes.
`f(a:b:r)=abs(a-b):f(b:r)` is a function yielding the absolute differences of the elements of an infinite list.
Given a number `n`, `(iterate f[n|n<-[2..],all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]]!!)` applies `f` `n` times to the list of primes. `length.fst.span(<3)` computes the length of the prefix of the resulting list where the elements are smaller 3.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 289 bytes

```
g(n:PI):PI==(k:=n*10;c:List NNI:=[i for i in 1..(k quo 2)|prime?(i)];repeat(a:=concat(c,[i for i in (k quo 2+1)..k|prime?(i)]);j:=0;c:=a;repeat(j=n=>break;j:=j+1;b:=a;a:=[abs(b.(i+1)-b.i)for i in 1..(#b-1)]);j:=2;repeat(j>#a=>break;a.j~=2 and a.j~=1 and a.j~=0=>return j-1;j:=j+1);k:=k*2))
```

ungolf it and test

```
f(n:PI):PI==
  k:=n*10
  c:List NNI:=[i for i in 1..(k quo 2)|prime?(i)]
  repeat
    a:=concat(c,[i for i in (k quo 2+1)..k|prime?(i)])
    j:=0;c:=a
    repeat
       j=n=>break
       j:=j+1
       b:=a
       a:=[abs(b.(i+1)-b.i)  for i in 1..(#b-1)]
    j:=2
    repeat
       j>#a=>break
       a.j~=2 and a.j~=1 and a.j~=0 => return j-1
       j:=j+1
    k:=k*2

(4) -> [g(i)  for i in 1..30]
   (4)
   [3, 8, 14, 14, 25, 24, 23, 22, 25, 59, 98, 97, 98, 97, 174, 176, 176, 176,
    176, 291, 290, 289, 740, 874, 873, 872, 873, 872, 871, 870]
```

it if not find the solution expand the prime list of 2*x in a loop and recompute all the remain lists. 3 seconds for find g(30)